# notification on email delivery failure with action mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

When I send an email to someone with action mailer in a rails 3 project

```
 mail(:to => @email, :subject=> "subject")
```

Is it possible for the controller to get notified if the message was delivered properly to the :to email address ,so that it will be possible to notify the sender about the email notification failure ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't check to see if somebody's received an email, but you can check to see if they've *opened* it. Email services these days use a small 1x1px image which contains some values in the query parameters to associate it to the user.

Other than that, no.

Comment: How will sending a small image notify me unless the user that received the email clicks on that image with the link ?

Comment: @Prabesh: the URL to the image is specially formed and should actually will hit your Rails application, the URL would be something like /emails/open.png?user_id=1&email_id=2. The endpoint for that then sends back a tiny image.

Comment: Note that you should expect around 43% of users not to load images. If you're traking emails and want some stats, remember that you should multiply this pixel stat by around 2. https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-data-analysis-reveals-image-blocking-affects-43-of-emails

Answer (score 2):

The deliver operation applied to a mail object will raise an error if the mail service it uses (e.g. mailgun) refuses it. I assume it's possible to rescue that error but haven't succeeded yet.

Answer (score 1):

ActionMailer does not do this inherently, but using a 3rd party delivery service like MailChimp will let you query their API (mandrill) and seek the delivery and 'opened' confirmations.

You could then extend ActionMailer to include hooks for these APIs and thereby-get notification.  The operation will be highly-asynchronous, and I'm not used to people storing and re-instantiating an ActionMailer object.  Feedback on that is welcome.